# How to keep my Electron app in foreground when I use getUserMedia(... chromeMediaSource: 'desktop')?

Tags: stream, electron, desktop, getusermedia

Like in this [Desktop Capture example](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/blob/master/desktop-capture/app.js#L71), I use getUserMedia() (or webkitGetUserMedia()) to screenshare a desktop app opened on my computer:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
            minWidth: 1920,
            maxWidth: 1920,
            minHeight: 1080,
            maxHeight: 1080,
            maxFrameRate: 25,
          },
        },
      })
      .then()
      .catch();
```

When I use this function, the window selected is focused and go to the foreground.

- How to avoid this behaviour and keep my Electron in the foreground?

I need to stay focused on my Electron application.

[image]

Comment: This may be a little glitchy / improper, but you could try calling `win.moveTop()` in the Enable Capture button click handler

Comment: Thanks @pushkin, "win is not defined", but first of all, even if it works, as you said, I think it will be glitchy.

Comment: `win` would refer to your window that you want to stay on top fyi